# git push fails in new branch

Tags: git

So I created a new branch in git by doing the following:

git checkout -b newbranch master

I made some changes in newbranch and committed them. git log shows my changes just fine.

Now when I do 'git push', I just get
'Everything up-to-date'
even though nothing was pushed to the remote repository.

I am on git 1.7.1

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git doesn't automatically push all branches.  Usually `master` is the default branch to push, but you can specify by doing:

```
git push origin newbranch
```

Although, you might want to instead *merge* your newbranch back into your master branch and then push that.

Branches in Git are more geared towards your own personal development that doesn't need to be shared with *everybody*.  One way to approach it is that you keep feature X hidden in a branch while you (and maybe a couple others) are hacking at it, and once feature X is done, you merge it back into `master` and *then* share it with the rest of the world.

Comment: You are a rockstar. Thank you so much, you have saved my sanity. It's 9.40pm and I thought I'd be here all night trying to get this figured out. Thank you! :-)

Comment: yep, I'm trying to - there's a 10 minute waiting period :-)